# Configuring Ports for Flink Job/Task Manager Metrics

Tags: apache-flink

I am running Flink in Amazon EMR.  In flink-conf.yaml, I have `metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9249-9250`
Depending whether the job manager and task manager are running in the same node, the task manager metrics are reported on port 9250 (if running on same node as job manager), or on port 9249 (if running on a different node).

Is there a way to configure so that the task manager metrics are always reported on port 9250?
I saw a [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8284) that we can "provide each *Manager with a separate configuration."  How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure different ports for the JM and TM by starting the processes with differently configured `flink-conf.yaml`.

On Yarn, Flink currently uses the same `flink-conf.yaml` for all processes.